STRIPE Silent payment to merchant from CC details save in stripe
So here is the process

The client saves user CC details to stripe from the custom UI.
The client makes a transaction to the merchant. (Merchant uses the Stripe Merchant onboarding process on merchant registration)
After a Successful transaction we run a cron job that automatically creates payment and checkout. Split the fee to the site and merchant.

Right now we can't find any possibility of automatically checking out the client. The payment session always shows Stripe UI and clients have to input CC details.

Is there a reason why you're not completing the payment when the customer is on-session and making the transaction? i.e. why are you creating the payment by running a cron job instead?
